# Can suitescript read all execution logs?

Tags: netsuite, suite

I wanted to write a suitescript to read all execution logs and spot those that have error logs. If not all logs, atleast those from our custom records. Is it feasible?

Answer (score 1):

If you are already familiar with searching in SuiteScript, the record ID for execution logs is `scriptexecutionlog`. You should be able to build your requisite search with `nlapiSearchRecord('scriptexecutionlog', null, [...], [...]);`